# Cannot read properties of undefined reading 'split'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I created a collection in Firebase's Firestore called **"locations"**, but the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')" keeps appearing when trying to "yarn start"

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Grid, Divider } from "@material-ui/core";
import Form from "../../common/Form";
import useForm from "../../common/useForm";
import Controls from "../../common/controls/Controls";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import DialogActions from "@material-ui/core/DialogActions";
import DialogContent from "@material-ui/core/DialogContent";
import DialogContentText from "@material-ui/core/DialogContentText";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { compose } from "redux";
import { firestoreConnect } from "react-redux-firebase";

import { signUp, resetAuthErr } from "../../../store/actions/authActions";
import { configs } from "../../../config/configs";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "#eaeded",
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(3),
    minHeight: "100vh",
  },
  grid: {
    height: "100%",
  },
  siginRoot: {
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    width: 350,
    [theme.breakpoints.down("xs")]: {
      width: 340,
    },
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
    border: "1px #ddd solid",
  },
  imageDiv: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    width: "100%",
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    boxSizing: "border-box",
  },
  logo: {
    width: 155,
    height: "auto",
    display: "block",
  },
  divider: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    marginTop: 0,
  },
  head: {
    display: "flex",
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
    paddingTop: 0,
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 700,
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  form: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    boxSizing: "border-box",
  },
  btn: {
    width: "97%",
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
    fontWeight: "bold",
    backgroundImage:
      "linear-gradient(to right bottom, #ff9b00, #e78a07, #cf790b, #b7690d, #9f590d)",
  },
}));

const initialFValues = {
  username: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
  confirmPassword: "",
  main: "",
  pincode: "",
  phoneNum: "",
};

const picodeSelect = [{ id: 0, title: "None" }];

function SignUp(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [dOpen, setDOpen] = useState({ open: false, msg: "" });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.authError !== null) {
      setDOpen({ ...dOpen, open: true, msg: props.authError });
      props.resetAuthErr();
    }
  }, [props.authError]);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (validate()) {
      if (values.password !== values.confirmPassword) {
        handleDifferentPassword();
        return;
      }
      var locations = props.locations[0].locations.split(",");
      var pincode = locations[values.pincode - 1];
      props.signUp({
        ...values,
        pincode: pincode,
      });
    }
  };

  const handleDifferentPassword = () => {
    setDOpen({
      ...dOpen,
      open: true,
      msg: "Please check your password fields",
    });
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setDOpen({ ...dOpen, open: false });
  };

  const getPincodes = () => {
    if (props.locations) {
      var locations = props.locations[0].locations.split(",");
      var res = [{ id: 0, title: "None" }];
      locations.forEach((location, idx) => {
        res.push({ id: idx + 1, title: location });
      });
      return res;
    } else {
      return picodeSelect;
    }
  };

  const validate = (fieldValues = values) => {
    let tmp = { ...errors };
    if ("email" in fieldValues)
      tmp.email = fieldValues.email ? "" : "Email field is required.";
    if ("password" in fieldValues)
      tmp.password =
        fieldValues.password && fieldValues.password.length > 6
          ? ""
          : "Password field is required and length greater than 6.";
    if ("username" in fieldValues)
      tmp.username = fieldValues.username ? "" : "Username field is required.";
    if ("confirmPassword" in fieldValues)
      tmp.confirmPassword = fieldValues.confirmPassword
        ? ""
        : "This field is required or check password again.";
    if ("pincode" in fieldValues)
      tmp.pincode = fieldValues.pincode
        ? ""
        : "We can't deliver to your area if your pincode is not in the list.";
    if ("phoneNum" in fieldValues)
      tmp.phoneNum =
        fieldValues.phoneNum &&
        fieldValues.phoneNum.length === 10 &&
        fieldValues.phoneNum > 0
          ? ""
          : "Phone Number is required.";
    setErrors({
      ...tmp,
    });
    if (fieldValues === values)
      return Object.values(tmp).every((x) => x === "");
  };

  const { values, errors, setErrors, handleInputChange } = useForm(
    initialFValues,
    true,
    validate
  );

  if (props.auth.uid) return <Redirect to="/" />;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid className={classes.grid} container justify="center">
        <Grid item>
          <div className={classes.siginRoot}>
            <div className={classes.imageDiv}>
              <img
                className={classes.logo}
                src="/imgs/logo.png"
                alt={configs.title}
              />
            </div>
            <Divider className={classes.divider} />
            <div className={classes.head}>Sign Up</div>
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <div className={classes.form}>
                <Controls.Input
                  name="username"
                  label="Your Name"
                  value={values.username}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  error={errors.username}
                  className={classes.input}
                />
                <Controls.Input
                  name="email"
                  label="Email Address"
                  type="email"
                  value={values.email}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  error={errors.email}
                  className={classes.input}
                />
                <Controls.Input
                  name="password"
                  label="Password"
                  type="password"
                  value={values.password}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  error={errors.password}
                  className={classes.input}
                />
                <Controls.Input
                  name="confirmPassword"
                  label="Confirm Password"
                  type="password"
                  value={values.confirmPassword}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  error={errors.password}
                  className={classes.input}
                />
                <Controls.InputArea
                  name="main"
                  label="Delivery Address (Optional)"
                  value={values.main}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  error={errors.main}
                  rowsMax={5}
                />
                <Controls.Select
                  name="pincode"
                  label="Pincode"
                  value={values.pincode}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  options={getPincodes()}
                  error={errors.pincode}
                />
                <Controls.Input
                  name="phoneNum"
                  type="tel"
                  label="Phone Number"
                  value={values.phoneNum}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  error={errors.phoneNum}
                />
                <Controls.Button
                  type="submit"
                  text="Sign Up"
                  className={classes.btn}
                />
              </div>
            </Form>
          </div>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Dialog
        open={dOpen.open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
      >
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
            {dOpen.msg}
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Controls.Button
            className={classes.btn}
            text="Cancel"
            type="cancel"
            onClick={handleClose}
          />
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    locations: state.firestore.ordered.locations,
    authError: state.auth.authError,
    auth: state.firebase.auth,
  };
};

const mapDispatchtoProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    signUp: (newUser) => dispatch(signUp(newUser)),
    resetAuthErr: () => dispatch(resetAuthErr()),
  };
};

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchtoProps),
  firestoreConnect([{ collection: "locations" }])
)(SignUp);
```

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to register users using Firebase, and "locations" is the user's address.I'm trying to register users using Firebase, and "locations" is the user's address.

**Firestore:**

[image]

Comment: Error message is clear - `props.locations[0].locations` is undefined. As to why it's undefined, that's up to you to figure out

Comment: @AdamJenkins Does .split() need to be declared? as it does not appear anywhere else in the code.

Comment: Given the code shown, the error is telling you that `props.locations[0].locations` is `undefined`.  When you debug, what is `props.locations[0]`?  Why do you expect it to have a property called `locations`?

Comment: @MariaFernanda [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) is a built in method that every string has. The code assumes that `props.locations[0].locations` is a string, but in reality your error states that it is `undefined`.

Comment: @David I edited the post, I'm trying to register users using Firebase, and "locations" is the user's address.

Comment: Your JS example was fine how it was because it illustrated perfectly what you were trying to do. All that was missing was the result from your Firebase store. With that we can see how the data should be treated.

Comment: @MariaFernanda: Yes, you seem keen on repeating that statement as many times as you can.  However, it doesn't really clarify the specific problem.  If you're not familiar with how to debug code, now is a great time to start.  The error is very simply telling you that what you're calling `.split()` on is `undefined`.  So if you're calling it on `props.locations[0].locations` then that means `props.locations[0].locations` is `undefined`, which means that `props.locations[0]` doesn't have a property called `locations`.  What **does** it have?  Your debugging can observe and find out.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Hi, I just added an image from Firestore

Comment: @David I understand, sorry if the question seems too basic, I'm just starting now.

Comment: Thank you. You're trying to access `props.locations[0].locations` (plural), but you should be accessing `props.locations[0].location` (singular).

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I tried but it didn't work either, when I changed it it didn't compile :(

Comment: @MariaFernanda [Please join chat to further investigate](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257092/cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-split).